# php-ffi: Return type const char* is a string

Tags: php, c, char, constants, php-ffi

Why is the result of `const char *` a `string` and `char *` an object „byte-array“?

A simple example:

```php
$ffi = FFI::cdef(
  "const char *strerror(int errnum);",
  "libc.so.6"
);
var_dump($ffi->strerror(1));
```

returns

```php
string(23) "Operation not permitted"
```

Removing `const` from the definition returns:

```php
object(FFI\CData:char*)#1074 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "O"
}
```

**Background**

A function of a dynamically linked external C library returns binary data which include NULL-bytes. When `const` is in the definition of the header file the resulting string is not complete = shortened to the first NULL-byte = corrupt file.

**My workaround**

Remove `const` from the definition and

```php
$array = $ffi->strerror(1);
$string = FFI::string($array);
```

returns the correct complete string.

(In the real-life scenario the $size for `FFI::string($array, $size)` is known and returned back from a different function of the C library.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping `const` or adding `unsigned` in the definition seem to be reasonable workarounds (cf. https://github.com/dstogov/php-ffi/issues/42#issuecomment-791237784)

**Examples**

Dropping `const`

```php
$ffi = FFI::cdef(
  "char *strerror(int errnum);",
  "libc.so.6"
);
$array = $ffi->strerror(1);
$string = FFI::string($array);
var_dump($string);
```

Adding `unsigned` (or changing to `uint8_t`)

```php
$ffi = FFI::cdef(
  "const unsigned char *strerror(int errnum);",
  "libc.so.6"
);
$byteArray = $ffi->strerror(1);
$charType = FFI::type('char*');
$castedValue = FFI::cast($charType, $byteArray);
$string = FFI::string($castedValue);
var_dump($string);
```